# Get value if checkbox checked

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery function to get the value of an checked checkbox.

How to hide the value in the span class "active-usb" if the checkbox is not checked anymore?

HTML

```
<span class="active-usb"></span><br>   
<input type="checkbox" id="getusb" value="Halterung für USB-Stick">
```

Jquery

```
$("#getusb").change(function(){
$('.active-usb').text($("#getusb:checkbox:checked").val());  
}).change();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `checked` property to determine if the checkbox is checked or not. Then you can get the value of the checkbox that raised the event using `this`. Try this:

```js
$("#getusb").change(function(){
  $('.active-usb').text(this.checked ? $(this).val() : '');  
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="active-usb"></span><br>   
<input type="checkbox" id="getusb" value="Halterung für USB-Stick">
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking how to *hide* it:

```
$('.active-usb').toggle(this.checked);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check ckeckbox status:

```js
$("#getusb").on("change", function() {
  //check if is checked
  if (this.checked) {
    //set the span text according to checkbox value
    $('.active-usb').text(this.value);
  } else {
    //if is not checked hide span
    $(".active-usb").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="active-usb"></span>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="getusb" value="Halterung für USB-Stick">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :-

```
$("#getusb").change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('.active-usb').text($(this).val());
   }  
   else{
     $('.active-usb').text('');
   }
}).change();
```

OR

```
$("#getusb").change(function(){
   $('.active-usb').text($(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : ''); 
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcdvd0o9/1/)

```
$("#getusb").on('change',function(){
    if($('#getusb').prop('checked')== true){
$('.active-usb').text($("#getusb:checkbox:checked").val());  
    }else{
        $('.active-usb').text('');  
    }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the isChecked and on inside a document.ready

```
$(document).ready(
    $("#getusb").on('change',function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $('.active-usb').text($(this).val());
       }  
       else{
         $('.active-usb').text('');
       }
    });
    )
```