# Pass multiple checked checkbox values to TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native, checkbox, textinput

Any idea how can we pass the values that has a checked checkbox? like if I checked checkbox no: 1,2,3 and etc.. then pass these to the Text Input

We can store the selected (checked checkbox) values in a class variable, for e.g this.selectedItem = item; when check box is true. Now we can use selectedItem anyway and anywhere we want, but I need to store multiple values.

Need to pass multiple checked checkbox values to TextInput React Native.

Comment: Be more specific about your question and add the code snippet or a link to your code.

Comment: can you please be more specific and what have you tried?

Comment: Here I can get checked checkbox value of one and it's replacing with new value and i tried to get second Checkbox value.

Comment: I tried this code and where i can get single checkbox value 

_myFunction(value,name,checked){
        this.selectedValue = value;
        console.warn("this.selectedValue = value : "+this.selectedValue)
    };
<Checkbox
 name={test}
 checked={false}
 size={30} 
 onChange={(name, checked) =>  this._myFunction(name[i],i, checked)}
/>

Comment: Can you please supply some visual representation of your requirement too? TextInput accepts only one string value or not?

Comment: TextInput with multiline can accept n' number of inputs(values),I just need to pass checked checkbox values(when it's true) to TextInput., for Ex: the way its working in below link and it's ReactJs and I need in react native https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851006/get-value-if-checkbox-checked

Comment: @Sana please post the code with the question it's barely understandable.

Comment: @Sana okay I got it replace the `console.warn("this.selectedValue = value : "+this.selectedValue)` with `alert("this.selectedValue = value : "+this.selectedValue)` and run it again

Comment: @Sana it worked?

Comment: I want to set these values to TaxtInput using setState(), but it's not happening and replacing with new checked values as I clicks on Checkboxe's